Возникает ошибка доступа к потоку при его повторном использовании внутри цикла
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       
        string strControl = null;
        string str = null;
       
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream("Text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        StreamWriter streamWriter= new StreamWriter(fStream);
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fStream);

        //Цикл для опроса пользователя
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Начало цикла");

            strControl = Console.ReadLine();

            //Выбор между чтением из файла и записью в файл
            if (strControl == "чтение")
            {
               
                while(streamReader.ReadLine() != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadLine());
                }
                streamReader.Close();

            }
            else if (strControl == "запись")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID сотрудника: ");
                str = Console.ReadLine();

                streamWriter.Write(str + " ");

                streamWriter.Close();

            }
            else if (strControl == "выход")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Повторите запрос!");
            }

        } while (strControl != "стоп");
      
        Console.ReadKey();
        
    }  
}

}

полезно
У вас методы streamReader.Close() и streamWriter.Close() закрывают поток, а после их закрытия доступ к потоку становится невозможным. Это вызывает проблемы при попытке повторного чтения или записи в файл. Чтобы избежать этой ситуации, используйте using вот еще док - автоматически управляет временем жизни потока и сам закрывает его по завершении работы
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strControl = null;
        string str = null;

        // Создаем и открываем файловый поток
        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream("Text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            // Создаем объекты для записи и чтения на основе одного и того же файлового потока
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fStream))
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fStream))
            {
                // Цикл для опроса пользователя
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Начало цикла");
                    strControl = Console.ReadLine();

                    // Выбор между чтением из файла и записью в файл
                    if (strControl == "чтение")
                    {
                        // Сброс указателя файла на начало перед чтением
                        fStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        
                        string line;
                        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                        }

                        // Сбрасываем буфер потока
                        streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
                    }
                    else if (strControl == "запись")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ID сотрудника: ");
                        str = Console.ReadLine();

                        streamWriter.WriteLine(str);

                        // Сбрасываем буфер потока, чтобы данные гарантированно записались в файл
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                    }
                    else if (strControl == "выход")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Повторите запрос!");
                    }

                } while (strControl != "стоп");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

старая версия использвоания using
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strControl = null;
        string str = null;

        FileStream fStream = null;
        StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
        StreamReader streamReader = null;

        try
        {
            fStream = new FileStream("Text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fStream);
            streamReader = new StreamReader(fStream);

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Начало цикла");
                strControl = Console.ReadLine();

                if (strControl == "чтение")
                {
                    fStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    string line;
                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
                }
                else if (strControl == "запись")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID сотрудника: ");
                    str = Console.ReadLine();
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(str);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
                else if (strControl == "выход")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Повторите запрос!");
                }

            } while (strControl != "стоп");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (streamReader != null) streamReader.Close();
            if (streamWriter != null) streamWriter.Close();
            if (fStream != null) fStream.Close();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

без использования using
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strControl = null;
        string str = null;

        // Создаем и открываем файловый поток
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream("Text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fStream);
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fStream);

        try
        {
            // Цикл для опроса пользователя
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Начало цикла");
                strControl = Console.ReadLine();

                // Выбор между чтением из файла и записью в файл
                if (strControl == "чтение")
                {
                    // Сброс указателя файла на начало перед чтением
                    fStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    string line;
                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }

                    // Сбрасываем буфер потока
                    streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
                }
                else if (strControl == "запись")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID сотрудника: ");
                    str = Console.ReadLine();

                    streamWriter.WriteLine(str);

                    // Сбрасываем буфер потока, чтобы данные гарантированно записались в файл
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
                else if (strControl == "выход")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Повторите запрос!");
                }

            } while (strControl != "стоп");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Закрываем и освобождаем ресурсы вручную
            if (streamReader != null)
                streamReader.Dispose();
            if (streamWriter != null)
                streamWriter.Dispose();
            if (fStream != null)
                fStream.Dispose();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


чтобы обновить версию языка

а) Перейдите на официальный сайт .NET
б) Выберите последнюю версию .NET SDK и скачайте установщик.
в) Запустите установщик и следуйте инструкциям на экране.
После установки вы можете обновить проект, указав в файле .csproj необходимую версию языка C#
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>


так же, обратите внимание, что в вашем коде вы используете один и тот же файловый поток (FileStream) для чтения и записи, что возможно может создать ошибку System.ObjectDisposedException : 'Cannot access a closed file.'
Я предложу использовать отдельные FileStream для чтения и записи. Для чтения - FileMode.Open и FileAccess.Read, а для записи — FileMode.Append и FileAccess.Write. Мне кажется, что такой подход разделяет потоки для одной конкретной операции
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strControl = null;
        string str = null;

        // Цикл для опроса пользователя
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Начало цикла");
            strControl = Console.ReadLine();

            if (strControl == "чтение")
            {
                // Создаем поток только для чтения
                using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream("Text.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fStream))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (strControl == "запись")
            {
                // Создаем поток только для записи
                using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream("Text.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fStream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID сотрудника: ");
                    str = Console.ReadLine();

                    streamWriter.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
            else if (strControl == "выход")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Повторите запрос!");
            }

        } while (strControl != "стоп");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

Я тестировала не на русском, потому что консоль у меня не выдает кирилицу, но вы поймете думаю, что файл успешно записался и прочитался
Début du cycle // начало
écriture // я ввела команду написать
ID de l'employé : 
25 // какое то Id
Début du cycle
écriture // еще ввожу запись
ID de l'employé :
35 // еще какой-то сотрудник
Début du cycle
écriture // для больше уверенности добавим еще запись
ID de l'employé :
88 // хорошее число, почему бы и да
Début du cycle
lecture // мы читаем файл с записью
25
35
88
Début du cycle
// затем я ввела команду выход в моем случае sortie и программа завершилась успешно


Спасибо за ответ. Проблема в том, что у меня версия языка не поддерживает использование using таким образом. Сейчас пытаюсь понять как ее обновить.

В c#-7.3 using прекрасно рабоает именно в таком виде, как в ответе. Без использования using нужно после цикла закрыть потоки и сделать им Dispose.

@Алексей, Я изменила свой ответ, добавив информацию по-вашему запросу

Я обновил версию и попробовал первый пример кода, и все же при попытке остановить цикл командой выход выходит сообщение об ошибки доступа к потоку. С чем это может быть связано?

@Алексей, Обновив код, разделила потоки для чтения и записи, что решило проблему, запустила тест. Теперь программа завершает выполнение без ошибок (?). Такой подход с раздельными FileStream для каждой операции — правильное решение, оно исключает подобные конфликты (с потоками при попытке остановить цикл) и делает код более надежным на мой взгляд

@Dev18 спасибо за помощь, я сумел разобраться в ситуации путем передаче потокам прямого пути к файлу. Ваш вариант был правильным, система конфликтовала из-за попыток доступа к одному потоку FileStream.
